# ModalPopUpExtender not showing the pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a modalpopUpExtender and trying to pop up list of ATM 
 .Following code  shows the ASP Panel where i want to do the pop up

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBanks" CssClass="atmBnkPopup" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="pnlBanksResource1">
        <div id="pnlBanksCnt" style="display: none;">
            <h2 class="sectionHeading">
                <asp:Literal ID="litATMPaymentHeader" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litATMPaymentHeaderResource1"
                    Text="ATM Payment (Indonesia)" />
            </h2>
            <asp:Literal ID="litATMPaymentText" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litATMPaymentTextResource1" />
            <br />
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCloseBanks" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lbCloseBanksResource1"
                    Text="&lt;img 
                        alt=&quot;Close&quot; src=&quot;images/btn/btn-close.gif&quot; __designer:mapid=&quot;5f&quot; /&gt;" />
            </div>
        </div>
         <asp:Button ID="btnBanks" runat="server" Style="display: none;" meta:resourcekey="btnBanksResource1" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeBanks" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnBanks" CancelControlID="lbCloseBanks"
        PopupControlID="pnlBanks" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DynamicServicePath=""
        Enabled="True" />
```

In the Aspx page, trying to call a JavaScript to pop up the screen

```html
<p>
  <asp:Literal ID="litATMBanks" runat="server" Text="To view the banks at which we accept ATM payment," meta: resourcekey="litATMBanksResource1" />
  <a href="javascript:ShowBankList();">
    <asp:Literal ID="litATMBanksLink" runat="server" Text="click here" meta: resourcekey="litATMBanksLinkResource1" />
  </a>
</p>
```

Here is My Java Script

```js
function ShowBankList() {
  var modal = $find("mpeBanks");
  if (modal) {
    $("pnlBanksCnt").style.display = "block";

    modal.show();
  }
}
```

I am getting Modal as null . 
I am not sure what is missing in the code . Why $find not able to find the element

[image]

Comment: Why do you have weird spaces in your HTML? `< p>` instead of `<p>` and `< asp: Literal` instead of `<asp:Literal`?

Comment: @mason, that came when i did formating in this page :( .

Comment: So fix it! We need to see what your code really looks like in order to be able to spot any potential issues.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are your familiar with CSS selectors and how they're used in jQuery? `$("pnlBanksCnt")` would retrieve any elements with a name of `pnlBanksCnt`, it would not retrieve an element with an ID of `pnlBanksCnt`.

Comment: Got 'display' of  undefined or null reference

Comment: That would probably be due to your invalid jQuery selector as I mentioned in the previous comment. In your jQuery use `$("#pnlBanksCnt")` to retrieve it.

Comment: It didnt help. Also first point is to some how get the value     var modal = $find("mpeBanks");  If i am able to get the value here ,  i may be able to find whats wrong with second part

Comment: You have the same issue there. You need to use proper selectors to get the object's you're seeking, `#mpeBanks`. You may also need to add a `ClientIdMode="static"` attribute to your extender. I don't understand what your code is doing though. Why are you doing an if statement on the result of that find statement?